# Installing pyfftw on mac OSX

Tags: python, pip, conda, fftw, pyfftw

I am trying to install `pyfftw` on mac OSX using `pip`. Here is what I have already done.

I have installed fftw using `brew install fftw`, and also tested the linking, by compiling and running the following code:

```
#include <fftw3.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, FFTW!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

with

`gcc -o test test.cpp -I/opt/homebrew/opt/fftw/include -L/opt/homebrew/opt/fftw/lib -lfftw3`

which runs fine and prints Hello, FFTW as expected.
After this I added the following lines to my `.zshrc` file:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/opt/homebrew:$PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-S,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/fftw/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/fftw/lib"
export CFLAGS="-Wno-implicit-function-declaration -I/opt/homebrew/opt/fftw/include"
```

When after sourcing the `zshrc` file I try `pip install pyfftw` from within a conda environment, I get the error message:

```
  ld: library 'fftw3f' not found
```

for each of the libraries and then finally says:

```
error: Could not find any of the FFTW libraries
```

I have checked the libraries are there.

From this message,  `DEBUG:__main__:Checking with includes ['fftw3.h']...ok` I believe it is able to locate the header file but the linker is not finding the libraries. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could be that the brew doesnt ship both single and double precision binaries..

Comment: check if `fftw3f` is actually present in `/opt/homebrew/opt/fftw/lib`

Comment: @FlyingTeller libraries are actually there.

Comment: @rasjani how to confirm it?

Comment: Why is Conda tagged? Conda users just use `conda install -c conda-forge pyfftw` and a precompiled version will be installed as well as a compatible version of `fftw3f` to what was linked against. No need to manually install libraries and mess with LD paths, etc., especially not changing them in `.zshrc`.